# Wrong tag stats?

Tags: bug, support

Is this a bug?

Steps:

1. Go to [tags](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags)
2. In the filter box type "business". You see two tags (business x 43), and (business-model x 7)
3. Click on each. [The page that opens for business](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business) shows 0 questions and says "You are on the Featured tab.
   There are no questions with an active bounty at the moment." You get [the same result](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business-model) with the other tag as well.

Comment: Are you on the "Unanswered" tab? If I switch to active, I get the number of questions matching the numbers you've listed.

Comment: @William'MindWorX'Mariager you are right, changing to active tab lists the questions. Yet, from UX perspective this is bad to default to an empty subset and show a message that has the tab's name wrong (the default tab is 'unanswered', which is referred to as 'Featured').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site remembers your tab choice when you return to tag navigation in many cases, so if you previously had the 'unanswered' tab selected, it will return you there the next time you view a tag list. Similarly, if you had the 'active' tab selected, it would return you there.

Some things do seem to cause this to reset, but for me it never resets to unanswered.

Also, when I'm on the 'unanswered' tab I don't see the text labeling it 'Featured,' so that's interesting.

Comment: It is strange. I could not reproduce the effect when I tried again now (even in an incognito window). One thing I am sure of though, is that I copy/pasted the text verbatim from the screen to my question.